# Does Chrome not support prototyped properties in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

Here's my code:

```
Image.prototype.x = 0;
Image.prototype.y = 0;

var blankImage = new Image();
blankImage.src = "blank.png";
blankImage.x = 16;
blankImage.y = 16;
```

In Firefox if I do `blankImage.x` it will return 16, but in Chrome it returns 0. Is there any way around this? I like this solution for my current problem..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome already defines `x` and `y` on image elements. Since you haven't inserted the element into the page, its `x` and `y` will be `0`.

Run this in Chrome's Console on a page with at least one image...

```
$$("img")[0].hasOwnProperty("x");
```

You will see that the `HTMLImageElement` already has that property directly on it, *not* on its `prototype` object.

You can also see it visually if you enter this in your console...

```
dir($$("img")[0]);
```

...and then expand the object.

The `x` and `y` properties are immutable can't be changed, hence they retain their value when you attempt to modify them (as if their [`writable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Writable_attribute) is `false`).

If you were to do the same with a property that doesn't already exist on a `HTMLImageElement`, it would work as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the DOM Image object is not part of any standard (it might be buried in HTML5 somewhere but I can't find it), it's a DOM 0 feature that existed in browsers around the time of standardisation and has persisted for compatibility ever since.

Browsers are not required to implement any kind of inheritance scheme, so expecting them to implement prototype inheritance is not reasonable. Futher, many browsers **don't** implement prototype inheritance on all, or any, DOM objects. So don't expect the DOM Image object to have a **prototype** property, or for properties set on a prototype object to be inherited by Image instances.

Documentation:
MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Image
MSDN Image object: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757809(v=vs.85).aspx#methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757809%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#methods)

Comment: Are you saying that it's not wise to assume `new Image instanceof Element === true`?

Comment: Yes. IE 8 in quirks mode and up to and including 7 in any mode does not implement any kind of inheritance for DOM objects. Recent browsers seem to do so, but it's not a good idea to take advantage of it for reasons other than lack of standardisation and support in some browsers, such as conflict with future properties and mixed environments.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what's going on, but I found that it depends on the name of the property you are setting, eg:

```
Image.prototype.hello = "hello";

var a = new Image();

a.hello; // Value is "hello";

a.hello = "goodbye";
a.hello; // Now it is "goodbye"
```

Tested in Chrome's console.

Comment: That's because an `HTMLImageElement` does not have a `hello` property (yet ;)